# Custom Post type field don't show in single machine

Tags: custom-post-types

Strange problem i am facing is that in one machine the custom post field don't shows up ( in all browsers chrome, FF in that particular machine ). But The same user login to different machine then it is showing. 
what may be the problem. Is that related to wordpress or admin issue.

Comment: Do you have Javascript errors in the console?

Comment: No i checked that no error

Comment: You are talking about a custom field and also about user logins. What is the relationship? And please post your relevant code.

Comment: @s_ha_dum It's just to make it clear that i have not assign custom field for different user and i don't think i need to add some code. As it is problem with one particular machine not with a single browser type. I have just added this question just to check has any one have face such issue ?

Comment: Ok, [have you validated the markup?](http://validator.w3.org/) Do you have a public URL for the broken site?